# Handing around Lists

Tags: c++

I have a question about lists in C++. I am creating a game, where there are a set of insects moving around the screen, and I do this by creating a class, initializing a list, storing the 'insect' object and then creating a draw and move function. Now, I want to be able to pass this list as well as a similiar list of 'insecticide spray' from another class to the 'main' loop, where the game loop is running continuously. Is this possible? If so how? And is it a good idea to do so? Passing whole lists back and forth?

Comment: You can simply pass a reference or pointer to the list. A more OO approach would be to wrap those list in an interface that wraps the operations made on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow Pen!

If it were me, I'd pass it by reference (especially if you have a lot of bugs...pardon the pun). It's definitely possible! This is just psuedo-ish code...but hopefully it can help 
you get going in the right direction!

```
#DEFINE BUG_MAX 100 // whatever you want this to be!
#include <list>
int main void(){
    BugClass bc = New Bugclass;

    for(int i =0; i < BUG_MAX; i++){
       bc.bugs(*i).yourmovefunction();
    }
}

class BugClass {
  list<Bugs> bugs;
//whatever else you want!
}
```

Kind Regards,

-sf

EDIT: Almost forgot to demonstrate the passing by reference!

Comment: What do you expect `*i` to do when `i` is declared `int`?

Comment: Kaz Maybe I should have used dereference operator? I was just trying to show that for every bug in the instance of his bug class he could execute his move function.


@BenjaminLindley To be honest, I think Pen just needed to see a concrete example of OOP in action. I wanted illustrate creating a class, and then instantiating an object of that class, and then accessing a member within it within the for loop. As I told Kaz, perhaps I should have used the & operator...my C++ might be a bit rusty there, I admit :) Still, I think conceptually, the psuedo-code works. Feel free to correct me there!